# Awkward line wrap in Yocto

Tags: bash, yocto

I'm building an embedded Linux system for ARM architecture using Yocto (thud release).

The image builds and I'm able to flash the board. However, when I connect over serial line, I get this strange line wrapping.

[image: Line wrap in yocto]

> You can see the character *h* overwriting bash prompt

The line keeps wrapping on the first line. Here is the environment:

```
guest@:ebox~ # printenv
LANG=C
EDITOR=vi
HZ=100
HUSHLOGIN=FALSE
USER=root
PWD=/home/root
HOME=/home/root
SHELL=/bin/sh
TERM=linux
SHLVL=1
LOGNAME=root
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
PS1=guest@:ebox\w \033[96m# \033[0m
_=/bin/printenv
```

I looked for solution and the best direction seems to be run with clean environment `env -i bash --norc --noprofile`

[image]

And the env:

```
bash-4.4# printenv
PWD=/home/root
SHLVL=1
_=/bin/printenv
```

**EDIT:** Ok I tried the PS1 prompt by enclosing the unprintable characters in brackets. It worked at that time on the booted system. So I changed the configuration in /etc/profile, built and flashed the system.

Unfortunately it’s not working and I get the same issue - the line wrapping.

Here is the content of the /etc/profile:

```
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
EDITOR="vi"                     # needed for packages like cron, git-commit
[ "$TERM" ] || TERM="vt100"     # Basic terminal capab. For screen etc.

# Add /sbin & co to $PATH for the root user
[ "$HOME" != "/home/root" ] || PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# Set the prompt for bash and ash (no other shells known to be in use here)
[ -z "$PS1" ] || PS1="$(cat /etc/device/hwid)@\h:\w \001\033[96m\002# \001\033[0m\002"

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
        for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
                if [ -f $i -a -r $i ]; then
                        . $i
                fi
        done
        unset i
fi

# Make sure we are on a serial console (i.e. the device used starts with
# /dev/tty[A-z]), otherwise we confuse e.g. the eclipse launcher which tries do
# use ssh
case $(tty 2>/dev/null) in
        /dev/tty[A-z]*) [ -x /usr/bin/resize ] && /usr/bin/resize >/dev/null;;
esac

export PATH PS1 OPIEDIR QPEDIR QTDIR EDITOR TERM

umask 022
```

I also turned on `checkwinsize` using `shopt` but didn’t work.

I also include the output of stty (over serial):

```
speed 115200 baud; line = 0;
-brkint ixoff iutf8
-iexten
```

And over SSH:

```
speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?;
-brkint ixany iutf8
```

I connect to the board over serial using screen on Mac. In minicom I get the same issue as do my colleagues on Windows using putty or screen on Linux. Same happens over SSH.

I also checked that the terming package and those files are installed correctly in /etc/terminfo.

EDIT:

I tried to change the size of the shell by using `stty cols 100 rows 40` and different sizes but the amount of characters I get on the line stays at 81 followed by carrige return. However if I record the session with `script` I get the correct amount of characters per line.

Here is my `stty -a` output:

```
speed 115200 baud; rows 24; columns 100; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>;
swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O;
min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon ixoff -iuclc -ixany imaxbel
iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon -iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho
-extproc
```

EDIT: 
 So I tested the behavior on HW and in QEMU. The reported issue is till present in `bash` on both platforms. However, when I run `busybox` i don't see such issue only resizing doesn't change the line width and if make the terminal smaller I get on the 80th character new line (in middle of text).

So the problem is probably tight to term being set to fixed size.

Comment: Try to intercept the data that go to your terminal emulator and see what sequence of bytes causes it. That should give some hints.

Comment: @JanChren-rindeal Thanks I did that using script. Seems the shell is not respecting the terminal size